# typescript how to transfrom undefined property to optional property

Tags: typescript

I have code like

```
interface Test {
  prop: number | undefined
}
```

and I want to transform the undefined property to optional property, such as

```
type ToOptional = ???
ToOptional<Test>
/** transform result
{
  prop?: number
}
*/
```

How should I define the ToOptional?

EDIT:

```
interface Test {
  prop1: number | undefined;
  prop2: number;
}

type ToOptional = ???
ToOptional<Test>
/** transform result
{
  prop1?: number
  prop2: number
}
*/
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use mapped types and conditional types to extract the properties that have `undefined` in them and then pick the `undefined` properties from the type. Simlarly we need to pick the properties that not undefined in order to get back all the original properties

```
interface Test {
    prop: number | undefined
    prop2: number
    prop3?: number
}

type UndefinedProperties<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]-?: undefined extends T[P] ? P : never
}[keyof T]

type ToOptional<T> = Partial<Pick<T, UndefinedProperties<T>>> & Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, UndefinedProperties<T>>>

type t = ToOptional<Test>
```

Comment: Great idea! Note: Without `strictNullChecks` enabled, this results in all fields being optional: [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false&strict=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5mQbwFDLIAOUA9kQFzIgCuAtgEbTIA+yNIAJhDKBJwG4CxMkQBMVWo2hDCJcgGYA-JPpMoQgL548YAJ5EUAVS48+nAAqjoYYJgA8qAHzIAvLmEBtC8lDIA1hB6pDBoALoAtCrsprwg-MgQAB6QXBho3mHISsg+khAAbjJ4mp6BwaGoYUK6BiiopADyRLakIHAANo4u7hZwULad9hbACP6OADTIJtxx-FbkNnYY3U4uAGTCI2OTyACiSQgdNNz25SFoUzNm8ZbWA8urTjXJRKQDyPqGaHREbmhNFrANpDdBYZ46BBtLCfX5UVC-f44TQ1KEgDCkDoQAB0HVIAHMABRgX4ASgEQA)

Answer (score 1):

With [key remapping via as](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as), we can have a cleaner version

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOrDACwKogCYQygR7IDeAUMtciHALYQBcyAzmFKAObIA%20yAV3yFieKjThdmtAfQBG0cdUwQANqoD2LIQSIgSS5AE8NAfhbtOILhQC%20FCmCMAHFABUI7ZAF5kAWTgAawgAeWcwYA06VQAedCxcXVEAPgoAejSaAD1TBwzkADENKGQ4ZAUwSGQnV2RMUDBkKLqNADdFGpQAUQAPZzh8GLdkn2Q3ZAgeyHxWZFAYaGQQ5FNyZABtAGk5kGRgkxglgF0WEK2j5FtkFn12qABuPMyAcQhGuHVqlWRWj4FPZAIKJgOCgbiCYR6EilfDIehBFBYCD0JrhSLRRwuFCJET6PAABSgGmcrCGEymEBmTTkACsIAgwCNfJQaBttqA9hADmNSrMdLjoZNpnhZm5zitkNsbhA7kdzGNznZkE9kABhDTyYjIADuGEwyCgnkaGkOSINEAEwAAjobSM4ia4oBFPJjagFgmEIlEPmShZSRdS6Qymchev1BjioQSHaThsgAGRLegYIYAGk53MjokJxNjyXzDkLDiAA)

```js
type UndefinedProps<T extends object> = {
    [K in keyof T as undefined extends T[K] ? K : never]?: T[K]
} 

// Combine with rest of the reuiqred properties
type MakeOptional<T extends object> = UndefinedProps<T> & Omit<T, keyof UndefinedProps<T>>
```