# Typescript type that allows omitting required object property

Tags: typescript

I don't know if what I'm trying to do is possible but here's the idea:

Let's assume we have a generic type:

```
type Foo<T> = {
  bar: T
}
```

Is there any `T` type which would let me omit the property completely, without making it optional in the type `Foo` (so without `?:` or `T | undefined`, etc)?

So this would pass compiler checks (where I'm looking for what `_` is)?

```
const x: Foo<_> = {}
```

Use case:

I'm trying to create a generic `HttpRequest` type, like so:

```
type HttpRequest<Body, Query, Path, Headers> = {
  body: Body
  query: Query
  path: Path
  header: Headers
}
```

And I'd like to be able to use it with any combination of the fields present, and I don't want to make all fields optional. Meaning I'd like to be able to do this:

```
const x: HttpRequest<{ test: number }, _, { foo: string }, _> = {
  body: { test: 1 },
  path: { foo: "bar" },
}
```

I used `_` as the magic type I'm looking for that lets me ommit the field.

Now I know I could do this:

```
type HasBody<B> = {
  body: B
}

type HasPath<P> = {
  path: P
}

// ....
```

And then combine these types:

```
type CustomRequest = HasBody<{ test: number }> & HasPath<{ foo: string }>

const x: CustomRequest = {
  body: { test: 1 },
  path: { foo: "bar" },
}
```

But it would save me a lot of time if the above mentioned type existed.

Comment: There is no `_` type that behaves this way but you can emulate it.  Can you test [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJ8GZN) against your use cases and let me know if you run into trouble?  I'm happy to write up an answer but keep in mind that there are probably tons of edge cases because it's not a normal thing to want to do.

Comment: @jcalz That's a clever solution, but I suggest using the `undefined` literal type (you can make `_` an alias of it) since that would be more meaningful than a class.

Comment: @kaya3 I guess the question is whether or not the OP cares about the sigil type `_` corresponding to something they could use accidentally.  You really want a nominal type there, but TS doesn't have them.  I'm happy to suggest that `_` should be any type they don't want to actually use as a property type, and if `undefined` is such a type then that works.  Maybe `never` is even better for that.

Comment: @jcalz I was thinking that if a property is allowed to be defined with the value `undefined` then it makes sense to also allow it to be, well, undefined. I can't think of any realistic scenario where you would want a type which requires a property to be present but always have the value `undefined`. The "transformer" type could then be like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56146819/typescript-how-to-transfrom-undefined-property-to-optional-property).

Comment: That's a pretty awesome solution @jcalz I don't really care what `_` is, so `undefined`, `void`, `never` etc basically anything works there that indicates the absence of the prop. If you make an answer I'll accept this right away! Thank you!

Comment: Okay I’ll write something up when I get a chance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking to *conditionally* omit properties from an object, based on whether or not the property is of some "special" type (which you're calling `_`).  There's no built-in functionality to do this, but you can build something that works this way:

```
type _ = never;
type Omit_<T> = { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends _ ? never : K]: T[K] }
```

You can define `_` to be any property type you don't want to support being part of the object.  I've chosen [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) here, but you could use `undefined`, or a nonce `class` type with a `private` member [to simulate nominal typing](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#when-and-why-are-classes-nominal), or anything really that won't interfere with "valid" property types.

Then `Omit_<T>` will take a type `T` and omit all the properties whose value is of the `_` type.  It does this using [key remapping in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as).

You can verify that it works:

```
type Z = Omit_<{ a: 1, b: 2, c: _, d: 4 }>
/* type Z = {
    a: 1;
    b: 2;
    d: 4;
} */
```

---

Armed with that, you can define `Foo`

```
type Foo<T> = Omit_<{
    bar: T
}>;

const x: Foo<_> = {}
```

and `HttpRequest`

```
type HttpRequest<Body, Query, Path, Headers> = Omit_<{
    body: Body
    query: Query
    path: Path
    header: Headers
}>

const y: HttpRequest<{ test: number }, _, { foo: string }, _> = {
    body: { test: 1 },
    path: { foo: "bar" },
}
```

Looks good.  There are probably caveats here, especially around type inference, so you should fully test against your use cases before adopting something like this.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA+lC8UB2EBuEBOBuAsAKFEigHkBbAS2BgB4AVAPgSgG8oBtAaSnKSgGsIIAPYAzKLSgBDAM7jOAXSgQAHsAhIAJrLgB+ZGkxQAXFA7yTtBVAC++fIWgAtJmUo1WkkwEYANFABGJgBMfgDGJjB+GiYALDb0+AD0AFRQDlDOiMz4ULlS3rh4eQHBhcXRUDGF1lDJiXYE4NAAYkJCdIyIrlTU2UV5-pIYFvjW9IX4oUJI0sBQyiat7TCdLLZ4DfZNUAASwMBgAEoQAI4ArhCz1ABCQhogfgCKFxgPUAAKksAAFn47EJINJhpKtuu4cgM7iATLd7hDcudMNCoM8kfCoGAvt8TJ8fujvgCgcNdoTgaMEhs8FMZnNkXsDsdEVdWGpZiYkGdSP5DNY-JEWFARG0TLMMDwAOY2PmrPrFfxQkwsy7AbxS9GYn6KwXCqAAIkGGF1arw63wQA)

Answer (score 0):

Type safety dictates that if a property might not exist on a type, then it must be optional. This allows you to use stricter tsconfig options and linters which will find type misuses in your code.

**The correct and proper** way to do what you need is via union types, which you are already aware of, as you mentioned:

```
type HasBody<T> = {
    body: T
}

type HasPath<T> = {
    path: T
}

type CustomRequest<T> = HasBody<T> | HasPath<T>;
```

This is 100% type safe, because typescript will require you to identify and cast to one of the specialised types before you can use the properties. You could identify them via decorators, or perhaps with an enum property common to all types.

I know that creating a type for each possibility might be time consuming, but type safety is why we use typescript, right? If was okay to assign an empty object to this, then the type would be meaningless and you might as well just use **any**.

Comment: I really don't see the type safety argument here, can you explain it?  What is "unsafe" about having a conditional type like `type Baz<T> = [T] extends [never] ? {} : {qux: T}`?  You can see that `Baz<never>` is `{}`, while `Baz<string>` is `{qux: string}`.  So depending on what type you specify for `T`, the type either does or does not have a `qux` property.

Comment: I'm interpreting the OP as asking for a type that *changes* whether a property is required, *depending on some condition*.

Comment: Union types are definitely not what I'm aiming for, intersection would work, but very cumbersome to use in my usecase. The solution @jcalz presented is perfect for this. There is nothing that will be "un-typesafe" about this, and that was never my goal either. Only downside is that it requires a bit of brainpower to understand the `_Omit` type for the first time reader.