# Transform a T | undefined key into a key?: T

Tags: typescript

In order to improve readability, I would like a transformer to take any type extending Record<string, any> and returning a type that makes keys that are undefinable optionals and obviously keeps the rest.

ie:

```
// I want to turn this
type WithUndefined = {
  a: string,
  b: number | undefined,
  c: boolean | undefined,
};

// Into this
type WithoutUndefined = {
  a: string,
  b?: number,
  c?: boolean,
}
```

I've found a way to do so, but it seems a bit convoluted for something I assumed to be simple. So much so that even VSCode doesn't resolve the type by itself in the overlay, making it annoying to read, completely ruining the goal.

```
type OnlyKeepsDefined<T extends Record<string, any>> = Pick<
  T,
  { [Key in keyof T]: undefined extends T[Key] ? never : Key }[keyof T]
>;

type OnlyKeepsUndefined<T extends Record<string, any>> = Pick<
  T,
  { [Key in keyof T]: undefined extends T[Key] ? Key : never }[keyof T]
>;

type RemoveUnionUndefined<T extends Record<string, any>> = {
  [Key in keyof T]: undefined extends T[Key] ? Exclude<T[Key], undefined> : T[Key];
};

type UndefinedToOptional<T extends Record<string, any>> = OnlyKeepsDefined<T> &
  RemoveUnionUndefined<Partial<OnlyKeepsUndefined<T>>>;

type TestType = {
  a: string;
  b: number | undefined;
  c: undefined;
};

type FilteredTestType = UndefinedToOptional<TestType>;

// Valid
const a: FilteredTestType = { a: "a" }; 
const b: FilteredTestType = { a: "a", b: 1 };
const c: FilteredTestType = { a: "a", b: 1, c: undefined };
```

Any ideas on how to improve it ?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56146819/typescript-how-to-transfrom-undefined-property-to-optional-property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the printing of the type with an `Id` type, that flattens it out:

```
type Id<T> = {} & {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P]
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-GoLOKwvO-WxquN2vRIeAIzbveT4DZmdlk-0xehlcR9ebm9uW9RBzdM6W3IA)

As to a simpler version, we can create one that filters the keys using the `as` clasuse, but the inetersection between the mapping of optional and required fields is still needed so not sure it's necessarily simpler

```
type UndefinedToOptional<T extends Record<string, any>> = {
  // We keep only keys that have undefined in the type and make them optional
  [P in keyof T as undefined extends T[P]? P: never]?: T[P]
} &  {
  // We keep only keys that do not have undefined in the type
  [P in keyof T as undefined extends T[P]? never: P]: T[P]
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgEwgMwJZwggKgewPJjCo5wCGANgDxZQQAewEiAzlAEoQDGOATgpc2A90AcwA0UUnBAA+GVAC8UAN4BYAFBQoAem1QA6tADWECGCglyIKCZCtgAC1LAoTgG7QArohTpMUdChHaFBISUQoAFtSEyCHCEiLQmIycg0tAG0ABQC4GwgQHGQoGlJWbyQ0DARaBiYEVixsgF0AfigsgC4oDA8eNu6mrOaNAF8oADItNU0dPUN8sws4K3y7OOcoBBwenBd3Lx8q-0DgoPAIdKhs3LWikslyo78a+kYWEpb23ogebuHBi0xlANKD1KFoFgIIIsBdFCorqRuoJhHARABuK4AI26cE8kSxvygAB8oBVfNVMbNON1yccEFTRlSNBCoAAxVDkRg8TBQmFwpTwSovXAEIgkCjUaHAWGQGTM9S6KAANQoqAQGm4cEEkm6HK5v150tl0CUyl1UAARKRLVAmZqSDqcezOdyjfywmaLdbLRJnQBGO1UrU6mkug087DGgUqb02v3df0SMN0l5BjRAA)